# Column data from Sql Server not position as match with column in Datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, epplus

The data in InvtID already match with "3" column once I import an Excel file, but the problem is as shown in the photo why the data column (InvtID) filled in datatable after the last row data? How am I able to fix the position to match with "3" column. I already position the InvtID column at 0. Is there any single line code to start position the row at 1?:

[image: program]

```
public void filldatagridview(ExcelWorksheet workSheet)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    //Create the data column
    for (int col = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Column; 
        col <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Column; col++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(col.ToString());
    }

    for (int row = 12; row <= 26; row++)
    {
        DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow(); //Create a row
        int i = 0;
        for (int col = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Column; 
            col <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Column; col++)
        {
             newRow[i++] = workSheet.Cells[row, col].Text;
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(newRow);                   
    }

    dt.Columns.RemoveAt(0); //remove No 
    dt.Columns.RemoveAt(0); //remove article

    //Get BookCode 
    var barCodes = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("3"))
        .ToArray(); //EAN column
    var barCodesstring = string.Format("'{0}'", string.Join("','", barCodes));
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT InvtID FROM InventoryCustomer WHERE 
        Barcode IN (" + barCodesstring + ")", conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);

    dt.Columns["InvtID"].SetOrdinal(0);
    dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: I did copy the column and add it as a new column, still the row is not start at index 1

Answer (score 1):

This code always adds a new row `DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();`, so your rows are not matched:

```
for (int row = 12; row <= 26; row++)
{
    DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow(); //Create a row
    //...
    dt.Rows.Add(newRow);                   
}
```

But if I understood correctly, you want to set data into specific data cells. Then you  should find existing row and set the cell value:

```
DataRow dr = dt.Rows[yourRowNumber];
dr[3] = "Your New Value";
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any solution to move all the range from CB037069 until IB093019 set at the first row instead of doing this for each data cell `DataRow dr = dt.Rows[1]; dr[0] = dt.Rows[16][0];`

Comment: Or it is possible to rearrange the //get BookCode from sql server along with the add of new row so that it will match side by side?

Comment: @Nebula9 For your the first question: As `Rows` property of `DataTable` has indexer , so you can get data just by index. So there is no way to move all range of rows .

Comment: @Nebula9 For the second question: anyway you should match columns of your data from SQL and Excel. Or you can order your data by `ID` and then just insert data from SQL and Excel if they share `Id's`.